# Empty catch but exception is still thrown

Tags: c#, exception

Have a look at the following source code

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetAntivirusSoftwareFromNamespace(string @namespace)
    {
        try
        {
            var wmipathstr = string.Format(@"\\{0}{1}", Environment.MachineName, @namespace);
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmipathstr, "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
            return from ManagementObject managementObject in searcher.Get()
                select managementObject.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
```

And I call it with the following piece of code

```
        antivirusSoftware.AddRange(GetAntivirusSoftwareFromNamespace(@"\root\SecurityCenter"));
        antivirusSoftware.AddRange(GetAntivirusSoftwareFromNamespace(@"\root\SecurityCenter2"));
```

As you can see, the expcetion is ignored - which works fine on my computer.
However if I run it on my staging server (which is Windows Server 2016 Standard) the exception is still thrown. Here's the stack trace

> Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.Management.ManagementException:
>   Ungültige Klasse    bei
>   System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus
>   errorCode)    bei
>   System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.d__94`1.MoveNext()    bei
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection)    bei
>   protocol.client.Service.Modules.Information.InformationService.GetAntivirusSoftware()
>   in
>   C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a41c7d46cc4907de\src\client\Service\Modules\Information\InformationService.cs:Zeile
>   70.

Any idea what could be the cause on this or how to fix it? I don't have visual studio or a debugger installed on the staging server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception isn't thrown within the method you've shown - you're basically returning a *query* to the caller, and that query is then failing.

One option would be to force the query to execute *immediately* by calling `ToList()`. That way, any exceptions would be thrown within the method itself, so you could catch them:

```
return searcher.Get()
               .Select(mo => mo.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString())
               .ToList();
```

Having said that, I'd strongly advise against having such an empty, blanket catch block - that basically says, "I don't care *what's* gone wrong, I want my code to keep running regardless, and I don't even want to log what the problem is." If you want to guard against `ManagementException`, catch that specific exception instead - and consider logging it so you can try to avoid it in future.

Comment: Ah damnit, you're totally right. The LINQ query is executed in return within the AddRange method... How could I be that stupid - obvious things are the worst.. Thanks alot!
And yeah, I'm gonna catch the ManagementException now, thanks for your advise!